# Transforming a set

Tags: ruby

I have a set of strings that I want to universally transform by running through a function, for example, `add_underscore(string)`.

Is there a native syntactic way to do this without iteration code?

Comment: Out of curiosity, were you using a `Set` or an `Array`?

Comment: A Set in order to take advantage of its searchability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000249) for applying a function to each element in a collection.

```
>> a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
=> ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
>> a.map { |x| x.upcase }
=> ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Building on The MYYN's answer…

```
set = [ 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four' ]

# in Ruby 1.9 this:
set.map &:capitalize  # => [ 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four' ]

# is the same as this:
set.map { |x| x.capitalize }
```

Note that `map` returns a new array, it doesn't modify the existing one. Also, it uses `enumerable` to iterate over each item in the array; it's still the best way to do this, just thought you might care to know.

Comment: Good to know, thanks!  It's fairly small so that's okay.  Syntactically it looks better than my old loop.